# what is the significance of using self.write intsead of return in tornado?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        return "Hello, world"

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

When I write return instead of self.write it gives me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1155, in _when_complete
    raise ValueError("Expected Future or None, got %r" % result)
ValueError: Expected Future or None, got 'Hello, world'
```

It did not understand what exactly does this `Values Error` means

I am using Tornado 3.1.1

Comment: "When I do something different from the thing I am supposed to do, I get an error." Well, yes.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman:Wow, what a comment, there is a reason for every changes that they made in their upgrade version.... check it out I got something for you to understand [You_are_Stupid](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

## In the file: web.py. Function 'get' does not return a value, that is 'return;' You must use self.write("Hello, World")

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    raise HTTPError(405)
```